# How to show the max in an array

Tags: ruby

The following program of mine is supposed to track each input, start a counter, and display the max input each time.

```
puts "Please enter an integer"
count=1
a = []
while count <= 10
  puts "this is the count #{count}"
  puts "this is the highest integer so far: #{a.max}"
  count = count+1
  input = gets.chomp
  a << input
end
puts "this is the highest integer #{a.max}" "\n"
puts a.max
```

But the program doesn't show the highest input in the array at the end. When I entered integers `10`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `111`, `300`, `400`, the value of `a.max` would reset to the input for each input until I got to 7, where it would repeat.

Comment: Don't forget instead of the stuff you're doing with `count` here you can do `10.times do` instead: One line instead of three, no variables unless you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `max` to get the maximum element among an array of strings. Try converting the introduced values to integer and at the end of the iteration you'll be able to get the max element among them:

```
puts 'Please enter an integer'
count = 1
a = []

while count <= 10
  puts "this is the count #{count}"
  puts "this is the highest integer so far: #{a.max}"
  count += 1
  input = gets.chomp.to_i
  a << input
end

puts "this is the highest integer #{a.max}\n"
puts a.max
```

Alternatively you could use `each_with_object` over an range assigning an array with initial value of 0 and start the iteration and "filling" the array:

```
puts 'Please enter an integer'

array = (0..9).each_with_object([0]) do |index, memo|
  puts "this is the count #{index}"
  puts "this is the highest integer so far: #{memo.max}"
  memo[index] = gets.chomp.to_i
end

p array.max
```